# Visual Studio loads another web site's master page in current web site design view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, master-pages

So I have a solution with two web sites in it. These are not website projects just web sites. They have their own master pages, which are named differently and reference style sheets that are also different names. For whatever reason both projects load the same master page and styles. I have tried toggling the "Set As Start Project" menu option and look through project and solution properties and cannot find anything searching the internet. This issue occurs in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.

If I add a new website and a new style sheet and a new master page all with unique names and even new css classes with unique names, I am still getting images and styles loaded from the first website I added to the solution when switching to the design view in the newly added web site.

Answer (score 0):

So having multiple file based websites in a single solution doesn't mesh well with the designer view of Visual Studio 2010 or 2012. I found a work around though. I just switched the websites to run on IIS Express and the designer view stop showing phantom styles, images etc. Make sure you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed and simply right click each website and select the IIS Express option from the menu.